# C++ Vector error messages:

Tags: c++, std

Is this error message because I am resizing a vector using an int instead of size_t? Or because I have to declare a copy constructor?

I am allocating elements using `vector_name[pos] = MyClass_Obj`, rather than using `vector_name.push_back(MyClass_Obj)`

> no appropriate default constructor available:
>
> see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_Uninit_def_fill_n<_FwdIt,_Diff,_Tval,_Alloc,Node>(_FwdIt,_Diff,const
>   _Tval *,_Alloc &,_Valty *,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
>
> see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_Uninitialized_default_fill_n>(_FwdIt,_Diff,const _Tval *,_Alloc &)'
>   being compiled
>
> while compiling class template member function 'void
>   std::vector<_Ty>::resize(unsigned int)'
>
> see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being
>   compiled

Comment: If it tells you that the error is "no appropriate default constructor available", I would take it at it's word that it wants a default constructor for this operation.

Comment: "I am allocating elements using vector_name[pos] = MyClass_Obj, rather than using vector_name.push_back(MyClass_Obj)". Just like I usually do addition using `x * y`, rather than `x + y`... Isn't that just hype?

Answer (score 3):

You should not insert that way.  `operator[]` is meant for accessing, not for creating.

If you do `vec[pos]` where `pos >= vec.size()` you're entering the land of undefined behavior.  `vec[pos]` returns a reference to the element stored at the index `pos`.  If there is *not* an element at the position, the implementation is free to do whatever it wants.

I would expect your code to crash and burn silently, not to give a compiler error.  What's probably happening though is that the vector implementation is trying to help you, and it's filling in the spaces between `size()` and `pos` with default constructed instances (well, trying to -- that would require a default constructor to exist).

In short: "I am allocating elements using vector_name[pos] = MyClass_Obj"

That's an abuse of `operator[]`.  `operator[]` should only be used to access elements that exist.  It should not be used to add new elements.  I'm actually surprised the vector implementation doesn't choke on that since I would imagine it would try to return a reference to something that's not an instance of the type.

Comment: `operator[]` isn't range-checked, and shouldn't be expected to expand the vector automatically.  But undefined behavior is a funny thing, the implementation is allowed to do *anything*.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's what I meant by "what's probably happening" and "not guaranteed," but will edit in a moment to makeover explicit not of the UD behavior.

Comment: I'd edit to say "bad things can (and *hopefully* do) happen..." since one of the worst things is to have it silently work for the wrong reasons, then break inexplicably later.

Comment: We can infer from the error message that OP is calling `.resize()`. From that we can further suppose that he is not accessing vector elements beyond the end of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Objects stored in a `vector<>` must be default-constructible. Yours are not.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() { /* This ctor is required. */ }
};

int main () {
  std::vector<MyClass> vec_name;
  vec_name.resize(10); // or else this will fail.
}
```

Comment: They don't really *have* to be default constructible -- but if they're not, you have to explicitly pass an instance as the second parameter to the ctor and/or `resize` (if you use it). If, for example, you ask for a vector of 10 objects, it'll copy-construct them from that object.

Comment: Apparently the OP has a default constructor, but hasn't since proven it.